# How can I write a makefile that can accept parameters from the CMD line

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gnu-make

So I am working to implement my own data structure that is similar to a linked list 
and I have created a make file that compiles my `.c` file with a test case file that checks to see if my implementation behaves correctly

The was I have my make file now work fine but if I need to change the test case I have to manually edit my make file

```
test:
        gcc -o test LL.c testcase00.c -g
        ./test

clean:
        rm test
```

I was wondering if there is a way that I can pass the number of the test case I would like to test when I call `make`, like `make 05` would automatically compile my `LL.c` with `testcase05.c` assuming all files are in the same directory.

Thank you!

Comment: easiest and the most natural with make is to pass variables like `make foo=bar all`

Comment: Ok im not sure how that works how would I apply it to my situation? would I change testcase to foo and then type testcaseXX.c when I call make?

Comment: I added an answer demonstrating the idea, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The below makefile will generate an executable `testcase` made out of an object file of one of the testcases.

When invoked like `make TEST_ID=02` it will use `testcase02.c`.

It's not explicitly pronouncing compilation rules relying on `gmake` explicit rules (usually works).

```
.PHONY: all
all: testcase

testcase: testcase$(TEST_ID).o
    @echo "making test $(TEST_ID)..."
    gcc $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Alternatively, if you need to build & run together, you can make it even simpler (using implicits for everything, it will generate and run an executable called `testcase$(TEST_ID)`):

```
.PHONY: all
all: testcase$(TEST_ID)
    @echo "running test $(TEST_ID)..."
    $^
```

Answer (score 0):

> bash$ make NN=05

In the Makefile:

```
SRC=testcase$(NN).c
test:
    gcc -o test LL.c $(SRC) -g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# default testcase
case ?= 00

test:
        gcc -o test LL.c testcase$(case).c -g
        ./test

clean:
        rm test
```

In this makefile `case ?= 00` sets default variable name. Environment variable and command line override this default value. So

```
make
```

will use `testcase00.c`

```
make case=05
```

will use `testcase05.c` and

```
export case=07
make
```

will use `testcase07.c`